# Coding for a congestion control algorithm

Tags: linux, algorithm, networking, tcl, ns2

I got the topic - designing an algorithm to prevent congestion in computer networks....
I studied various sources and for you an idea about the model that I'm going to propose.....
But I don't know where to code and how to code and what to code in this position......
I'm pretty good at programming but I'm in a daze not able to move from here.....
Anyone plz help me by showing me a way to execute it....
Note : I'm using Linux as an environment, nsg tool for protocol scenario testing , and an APP( automated post processing) tool for testing the algorithm...

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking. Could you please tell us a little more about something specific? What language are you intending to develop in? What is a specific problem you are having right now that is preventing you from making the next step?

Comment: Ok....I'm using tcl to code.....my idea is...." We usually see packets dropped in a network when congestion occurs. Now, in my algorithm, I want to minimise the packet drop to a large extent. So we are going to route the path of data packets in such a way where the control of flow of packets should choose an alternate path when a congestion is occurred...!!! Instead of immediate packet dropping....

Comment: The specific problem what I have now is.... I'm unaware what to do next ... How to write tcl code for this.... Need several references for this ... And how to use one such algorithm in nsg tool...

Comment: I personally do not know anything about TCL, but to help you get the answers you need I suggest editing your question to reflect what you just told us in the comments. You can also try adding a tag for TCL so that the experts who actively brows their subject area can quickly find your question. And welcome to the site by the way!

Comment: This for a course? Talk to your tutor.